# FAILED: tests/plugin/libinsn.so when building QEMU on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: linux, makefile, ubuntu-16.04, qemu

I'm trying to build QEMU on a Ubuntu 16.04.3 VirtualMachine following [these instructions](https://github.com/k0nze/qemu_zynq_linux_setup).

The problematic part is executing command `make -j4`, after some trials I found the correct configuration command to be ran before `make -j4` is:

```
./configure --python=/usr/bin/python3.7 --cc="gcc-7" --extra-ldflags="-pie -fPIC" --extra-cflags="-fPIC" --extra-cxxflags="-fPIC" --target-list="arm-softmmu" --enable-fdt --disable-kvm --disable-xen
```

With this configuration `make -j4` runs and builds [2290/2594] elements, but it fails when `Linking target tests/plugin/libinsn.so` with the following error:

```
FAILED: tests/plugin/libinsn.so 
gcc-7 -m64 -mcx16  -o tests/plugin/libinsn.so tests/plugin/libinsn.so.p/insn.c.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -shared -fPIC -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-soname,libinsn.so -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -fPIC -pie -fPIC -pthread -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -Wl,--end-group
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
tests/plugin/libinsn.so.p/insn.c.o: In function `plugin_exit':
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:82: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_outs'
tests/plugin/libinsn.so.p/insn.c.o: In function `vcpu_tb_trans':
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:39: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_tb_n_insns'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:46: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_register_vcpu_insn_exec_inline'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:43: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_tb_get_insn'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:49: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_insn_vaddr'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:50: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_register_vcpu_insn_exec_cb'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:56: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_insn_size'
tests/plugin/libinsn.so.p/insn.c.o: In function `vcpu_insn_exec_before':
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:31: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_outs'
tests/plugin/libinsn.so.p/insn.c.o: In function `qemu_plugin_install':
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:93: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_bool_parse'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:98: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_bool_parse'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:112: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_register_vcpu_tb_trans_cb'
/home/MY_PATH/qemu/build/../tests/plugin/insn.c:113: undefined reference to `qemu_plugin_register_atexit_cb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to fix it?
If more info is needed ask and I'll provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has now fallen out of the supported window for upstream QEMU. (The support policy is "most recent LTS, and previous LTS for 2 years after a newer one appears", so currently 18.04 and 20.04 are still OK.) 16.04 is also no longer in security support for Ubuntu itself. I would recommend using a newer host OS.

Comment: That said, if you don't care about TCG plugins (which is what is failing to build here), you can disable them by adding --disable-plugins to your configure command line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'd like to use QEMU to emulate a PetaLinux image which requires Ubuntu 16.04.3 to be generated. I'll try to install a new VM with a newer version of Ubuntu hoping it works.